# Printing out registers/ints to console | FASM | WINAPI

Tags: winapi, assembly, fasm

Just wondering if there was a way i could print out a number to the console
by invoking. it can be either base 10, or hex I don't mind.

I would like to see the format in which some functions return.

I would prefer not to do it the long way using WriteConsole and a lot of asm

P.S also this is my first question , how do i accept an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) from msvcrt.dll:

```
                format PE console
                include "win32ax.inc"
start:
                cinvoke printf,formatstring,eax
                invoke  Sleep,-1

formatstring    db "%d",13,10,0

section '.idata' import data readable

library msvcrt,'msvcrt.dll',\
        kernel32,'kernel32.dll'

import  msvcrt,printf,'printf'
import  kernel32,Sleep,'Sleep'
```